# How do I apply a PostgreSQL function to a query using Clojure?

Tags: postgresql, clojure, clojurescript, clojure-java-interop

```
(ns training-clj.querys
  (:require [honey.sql :as honey]
            [next.jdbc.sql :as jdbc]))

(defn get-by-username
  [db username]
  (let [query (honey/format {:select [:*]
                             :from   [:user]
                             :where  [:= :username username]]})]
    (jdbc/query db query)))
```

I'm doing a query in the db (postgresql) per user and I have a return similar to this: `({:id 2 :username "random" :age 18 :telephone 3120-4587})` and given this code base that I defined, I want to apply the PostgreSQL LOWER() function to the :username key, what are the ways I can do this?

Comment: This function does not return a single string. It returns most likely a list of "users". Where do you want to use the lower-function exactly? For the comparsion?

Answer (score 2):

You're using HoneySQL, so calling a PostgreSQL function should be done via HoneySQL's DSL. The relevant part is described [here](https://cljdoc.org/d/com.github.seancorfield/honeysql/2.5.1091/doc/readme?q=function#functions).

As for your specific question, it's unclear what the `lower` function must be applied to since `:*` returns all columns.

But let's assume that you want to return `:first-name`, just lower-case. Then it would be something like this:

```clj
{:select [[[:lower :first-name]]]
 ...}
```

or

```clj
{:select :%lower.first-name
 ...}
```

Comment: perfect, it worked, i'm sorry for not being able to explain it clearly, I'm a beginner at this, but can you tell me how I can apply the lower key to the query key as well?

Comment: @django What do you mean by the "query key"? If you mean the username on which you're filtering in the original query, then it's `{... :where [:= :%lower.username username]}`.